# Draw downloaded icon chrome extension

Tags: canvas, google-chrome-extension, icons

I use this example for setting extension icon from url.

```
                                var img = new Image,
                                canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
                                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                                src = settings['address'] + "/2.png"; // insert image url here

                                img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

                                img.onload = function() {
                                    canvas.width = img.width;
                                    canvas.height = img.height;
                                    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
                                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({"imageData" : ctx.getImageData(0,0,19,19)});

                                };

                                img.src = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/krl72AYWGWgmhSCcdlHm-IgwkOBfdq6qVFIJtHxhfoSlMcrIgKdVhK-l-o800kv0m7uO=w300';
```

But in the end I get a stupidly transparent icon, not even an icon but a void. There is no mistake.

Comment: Check the console in devtools for the page that runs 
 the code. The background page has a separate console. As well as the popup.

Comment: @wOxxOm i checked. No errors.